# oc / kubernetes: deployment returns "unrecognized type: string" while adding environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, openshift-3

We are deploying with Ansible scripts to Openshift 3 using `oc apply`. When we change template to add more environment variables, we receive a very vague error: `"unrecognized type: string"` and status code 500.

Setting `--loglevel 10` leads to no more details:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/oc_v3.11.715 apply -f \"/tmp/ansible.YtEqVm_deploy/app.yml.json\" -n test-env --loglevel 10 2&> log.log

(several GET to get secret, deploymentconfigs, etc.)
...
I0127 11:49:05.455217     605 request.go:897] Request Body: {xxxxxxxx}
I0127 11:49:05.455280     605 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XPATCH  -H "User-Agent: oc_v3.11.715/v1.11.0+d4cacc0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/d4cacc0" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" 'https://test-env:8443/apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/test-app/deploymentconfigs/app'
I0127 11:49:05.466278     605 round_trippers.go:405] PATCH https://test-env:8443/apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/test-env-app/deploymentconfigs/app 500 Internal Server Error in 10 milliseconds
I0127 11:49:05.466287     605 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0127 11:49:05.466291     605 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 118
I0127 11:49:05.466294     605 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2023 09:49:05 GMT
I0127 11:49:05.466297     605 round_trippers.go:414]     Audit-Id: 1d3f3398-14fc-4bfa-854b-6faf9b105680
I0127 11:49:05.466302     605 round_trippers.go:414]     Cache-Control: no-store
I0127 11:49:05.466307     605 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I0127 11:49:05.466321     605 request.go:897] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"unrecognized type: string","code":500}
I0127 11:49:05.466603     605 helpers.go:201] server response object: [{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "unrecognized type: string",
  "code": 500
}]
F0127 11:49:05.466618     605 helpers.go:119] Error from server: unrecognized type: string
```

The request body is like:

```json
{
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "spec": {
                "$setElementOrder/containers": [{
                    "name": "app"
                }],
                "containers": [{
                    "$setElementOrder/env": [{
                        "name": "OLD_VAR_1"
                    }, {
                        "name": "OLD_VAR_2"
                    }, {
                        "name": "OLD_VAR_3"
                    }, {
                        "name": "OLD_VAR_4"
                    }, {
                        "name": "NEW_VAR_1"
                    }, {
                        "name": "NEW_VAR_2"
                    }, {
                        "name": "NEW_VAR_3"
                    }],
                    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                    "env": [{
                        "name": "OLD_VAR_4",
                        "value": false
                    }, {
                        "name": "NEW_VAR_1",
                        "value": 10
                    }, {
                        "name": "NEW_VAR_2",
                        "value": 20
                    }, {
                        "name": "NEW_VAR_3",
                        "value": 6
                    }],
                    "name": "app",
                    "restartPolicy": "Always",
                    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 300
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`OLD_VAR_x` are old environment variables; we want to add `NEW_VAR_[1-3]`. Notice strangely that not all old vars are in `env`, only `OLD_VAR_4`, but all new vars are in `env`.

This also happens when we use `oc patch` with the same request body. Same error response.

What is wrong?

A workaround is first, deployment, fail, and add new vars in Openshift manually, and deploy in Openshift webconsole on top of the last, failed deployment. It works.

Comment: The json which is getting applied is for which kind of kubernetes object.  Also without "kind" mentioned in json to which the object k8s has to apply the value to

Comment: Can you show us an Ansible playbook and template that reproduces this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by quoting the var values in the template, like:

```
- name: NEW_VAR_X
  value: "${NEW_VAR_VALUE_X}"
```

No errors ever since.